# Scrolling down while selecting text in PuTTY

Tags: windows, putty, less

Is there anyway we can copy large amount of text to Windows clipboard from file opened through `less` command? While it's easy to select text that is appearing on the screen, but how to continue selecting while scrolling down in PuTTY?

We can scroll down through up and down button or Page UP and page Down button.

Answer (score 1):

These work:

- While dragging the mouse cursor to extend the selection, move the cursor outside of the PuTTY window (above or below) to start scrolling.
- Use the mouse wheel, while holding down the mouse button.
- Use the <kbd>Shift+PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+PgDn</kbd>, while holding down the mouse button.

---

Note that there's also *Copy All to Clipboard* command in the context menu of PuTTY window title.

Comment: I remember there used to be a key on keyboard that we need to keep pressing while selection on scrolling up or down, I am not recall that key though

Comment: Sure, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I think people might still be interested.   I use the Copy/Paste function to back up router configs and sometimes complicated strings of commands in the Cisco/Juniper/Foundry Routers and switches like ACLs or complicated BGP configs as well as things like starting and stopping BGP sessions you might want to do quickly that take a series of commands.

First thing is to do "terminal length 0" so it won't page.    Then issue your "show whatever" command. You can start selecting and use the Shift+Pg(up|down) but for long ones what I do is clear the scrollback first (from the putty menu) and use Shift+HOME/END (while holding the mouse button to highlight the entire text.  Sometimes you seem to have to move the mouse slightly for the selection to take effect, or maybe I am just impatient and it would have done it anyway.

Most serious routers will let you enter the config mode and paste these commands right back in.   I often add the "config terminal" and "exit" commands to both ends of the text file so I can just select it all, right click to paste into the terminal window and be done with CTRL-A/CRTL-C in notepad and a right click in the router config window.